# websocket show error Error: The delegate target that is being invoked is no longer available. Please check if it has been prematurely GC'd.Uncaught

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, runtime-error, blazor-webassembly

I use .net core system.NetWebSockets, initially get the data well, but after a while, these error phrases appear, and the websocket stops.

```
Error: The delegate target that is being invoked is no longer available.  Please check if it has been prematurely GC'd.Uncaught
```

How Can I fix it? thank you.

Comment: As the error message said, the delegate target that is being invoked is no longer available.  Please check if it has been prematurely GC'd.Uncaught. Can you post the related code or create a simple sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: thank you. it's solved by update .net core to version 6